# open NgbTypeahead dropdown when click event on button

Tags: focus, dropdown, ng-bootstrap, typeahead

I need to simulate focus event on input to open NgbTypeahead dropdown , is it possible? Because i cant do it like:

.ts:

```
@ViewChild('inputExecutor') inputExecutor: ElementRef
focus$ = new Subject<string>();
click$ = new Subject<string>();

focused(){
    this.executorForm.controls['executor'].setValue('');
    this.focus$.next(this.executorForm.value.executor);
}

inputFocus(){
    this.inputExecutor.nativeElement.focus();
}


html:

     <input
             class="choose-executor-input"
             type="text"
             name="executor"
             formControlName="executor"
             [ngbTypeahead]="searchExecutors"
             (focus)="focus$.next($event.target.value); focused()"
             (click)="click$.next($event.target.value);"
             (selectItem)="itemSelected($event)"
             [resultFormatter]="formatExecutors"
             [inputFormatter]="formatExecutors"
             #instance="ngbTypeahead"
             #inputExecutor/>
     <button 
            click)="inputFocus()"
            class="btn btn-executor-open"></button>
    </button>
```

So how i can focus on input to open dropdown? Any issues?

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this, you can fire an input event on the input element the NgbTypeahead is bound to, then call the focus method so that the input has focus and you can start typing immediately.

I started with the [Open on focus](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples#focus) demo from the ng-bootstrap website, and made the following changes:

Declare a new template variable `elem` so the DOM element is accessible inside the component TS file (note you can't use the existing `instance` as that is an NgbTypeahead not an HTML element):

**Component HTML:**

```
<input
  id="typeahead-focus"
  ...
  #instance="ngbTypeahead"
  #elem
/>
```

**Component TS:**

```
@ViewChild('elem') elem: ElementRef;
```

Add a button to the template which will call a focus function - this is the button that when clicked will open the typeahead and focus on it:

```
<button (click)="openTypeahead()">Open Typeahead</button>
```

Add an `openTypeahead` function in the component TS file as follows:

```
public openTypeahead(): void {
  // Dispatch event on input element that NgbTypeahead is bound to
  this.elem.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
  // Ensure input has focus so the user can start typing
  this.elem.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

Please see [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dsmj6k?file=app%2Ftypeahead-focus.ts) for a demo

Answer (score 0):

I use

HTML:

```
<input #instance="ngbTypeahead" .../>
<button (click)="openTypeahead(instance)">Open Typeahead</button>
```

TS:

```
openTypeahead(inp) {
    inp._elementRef.nativeElement.value = '';
    inp._elementRef.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    inp._elementRef.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: The `_elementRef` property is private to the ngbTypeahead class and will throw errors. Especially if you try a production build in Angular. Is there another way to solve the problem?